# Which are common DDD (Domain-Driven Design) patterns?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Specification pattern is a common pattern used in DDD that encapsulate business logic to respond to one question.

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T aSource);
}

public class CustomerHaveDiscountSpec : ISpecification<Customer>
{
   bool IsSatisfiedBy(Customer aCustomer)
   {
       /* ... */
   }
}
```

Which other patterns are common in Domain-Driven Design?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend InfoQ's [Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly), which does a good job of distilling the (too) longer book by Eric Evans. Building upon @Pangea's answer, the objects list deserves some description:

- **Repository**: encapsulates persistence and search - typically database
- **Service**: stateless API entity used for aggregate root CRUD
- **Aggregate Root**: an entity whose other child composite entities lack appropriate meaning without it - perhaps the most important aspect from an API perspective when talking about DDD
- **Value Object**: entity whose state does not change after instantiation (e.g. Color), particularly useful in multithreaded programming because using such eliminates concurrency issues

Comment: Eight years on, still too long. DDD is talked about way more than implemented. Its desire for OO purity is noble, but impractical.

Comment: I would add:

* Mappers
* Entities
* Ports & adapters

Answer (score 6):

I do not think we call this as patterns but some concepts are repository, aggregate root, value object, entity, domain services, application services. Below two links are helpful

http://dddcommunity.org/resources/ddd_terms

https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-domain-driven